# Tick Marks not Displaying - Tkinter Scale

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-scale

None of the tkinter `Scale`s I've made show tickmarks.

I tried pasting other people's code into my editor and same result, no ticks. The example is utterly simple so I couldn't think of anything to try except different values for the `tickinterval` option. I'm using tkinter 8.6 with python 3.5. Thanks for any assistance.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

flt = tk.Scale(
    root,
    label="No Ticks", 
    from_=50.0, 
    to=200.0, 
    length=900, 
    orient="horizontal", 
    resolution=25, 
    tickinterval=50.0)

flt.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

There are no error messages and everything else seems to work.

Comment: When I run your code I see the tick marks. They aren't little dots or bars, the "tick marks" are the numbers 50, 100, 150, and 200 that appear below the scale. Are you saying you don't see those numbers?

Comment: @ Bryan Oakey, thanks for clearing that up. I see now that the numbers appear at the tickinterval. I had been expecting to see little lines or dots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option `tickinterval` does not refer to tick marks but to the numbers displayed along the `Scale`.

Once this was pointed out by Bryan Oakley in the comments, I was able to glean the following information from running simple examples, which I had not found in the docs. Basically, the `resolution` option and the `tickinterval` option values need to be considered together for both to work as desired.

**`tickinterval`**

Using the default value of zero, the only number shown will be the one which names the position of the slider. Otherwise the `tickinterval` will be the distance apart of numbers marking positions on the Scale. To be sure `tickinterval`s will be displayed as desired, this should be set to an even multiple of `resolution` e.g. if `resolution` = 100, `tickinterval` should be 200
or 300 etc. If `resolution` is set to 0 or -1, `tickinterval` will display at any increment desired.